# Can we use t-test to liner combination of random variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose X and Y are two random variables.

And I have some samples of them:

[9, 10, 11, 9, 10, 8, 10] and [100, 99, 101, 110, 120].

I want to test if Y is statistically larger than 10*X,

#### Question:

Can I use t-test and assume `H0: 10*X ≤ Y` with `alpha=0.05`?

I am asking because I have never seen any case that applies 10* before a random variable. All examples tell me I can use `H0: X ≤ Y` instead of `10*X ≤ Y`

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you stuck? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I fix the question, could you please take a look?